# Sort date column dd/mm/yyyy fromat Jqgrid

Tags: javascript, date, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid grid and it has a date table. The date is in dd/mm/yyyy format. I want to sort the column by clicking colomn header. I use
 `sorttype : 'date',formatter:'date', datefmt: 'd/m/Y'`
on my column properties. But after using this formatting the date data is changed and they are wired. Can anyone help me to sort date column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is in the small misunderstanding of the meaning of `datefmt` option. It will be used only if  you use `sorttype: "date"` (or `sorttype: "datetime"`) **without** `formatter: "date"`. On the other side if you use `formatter: "date"` you should specify `formatoptions` with `srcformat` and `newformat`. So you should either remove `formatter: "date"` or add `formatoptions: { srcformat: "d/m/Y", newformat: "d/m/Y" }`. If the input data are already in the format `d/m/Y` which you already use to display the data it's more logically in my opinion just to remove unneeded `formatter: "date"`.